# How to debug why my graph isn't showing the data properly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I ran into a problem here. Code for the DataFrame (I have created using MySQL):

```
import mysql.connector as mc

pat = 'create table Patient(ID char(10) primary key,PName varchar(20),Phone int(10),Age int(3),BloodGrp char(3),Qty_needed char(5),Gender char(1))'
cursor.execute(pat)

sql1 = 'Insert into Patient(ID,PName,Phone,Age,BloodGrp,Qty_needed,Gender) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'
val1 = [
        ('pat1','Aaron J',93242995,26,'B-','3L','M'),
        ('pat2','Nyra J',97671637,30,'AB+','1.5L','F'),
        ('pat3','Niharika K',96157527,42,'A+','2L','F'),
        ('pat4','Abdullah M',99936373,25,'O+','1L','M'),
        ('pat5','Ezra D',91512623,29,'B+','3L','M'),
        ('pat6','Vihan S',92397991,45,'B-','4.2L','M'),
        ('pat7','Jessi A',34534255,17,'A+','3L','F'),
        ('pat8','Deepak K',34534255,42,'O+','1.4L','M'),
        ('pat9','Ameya P',84723992,27,'B+','2L','F')
]

cursor.executemany(sql1, val1)
mydb.commit()
```

Code for the graph :

```
x2 = df[4]
y2 = df[5]
mplt.title('Donor')
mplt.xlabel('Blood Group →')
mplt.ylabel('Amount Donated →')
mplt.ylim(0,6)
mplt.bar(x2,y2,color = 'coral')
```

My aim is to display how much amount of blood has been donated in each blood group.

Although I am not getting error, the problem is I'm not able to define the y axis properly

I have enclosed the picture of the graph:

[image]

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what do you expect in the chart? I can see you have a duplicate record for B-. I guess you are missing a groupby and a proper aggregation. But that's my guess as I do not know what you want to visualize

Comment: My aim is to display how much amount of blood has been donated in each blood group

Comment: Hi @Thakshaya, thanks for your question. Can you be more specific about the output you would like to see? Also if you can be so kind to provide a data sample in your question, that one can copy.

Comment: @DataBach I have added the code for the DataFrame